# All users to work on certain records only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan

I have cancan and devise installed. Right now it simply limits the user to being logged in and certain controllers. I want to expand the permission where the user can only access the records of the company they work for:
* Mailers are mailing we do to prospects.
* Customer_order are of course customer orders.

```
user.company_id == mailers.company_id 
OR user.company.id == customer_order.company_id
```

If these match then the user can perform CRUD on those records.

Answer (score 0):

Simply check the permissions in a `before_filter`.
If you have a `companies_controller` you could do it this way:

```
before_filter :check_permission, only: [:show, :new, :create] # and all the actions you want to protect

# Your actions

private

def check_permission
  # current_user is available if you're using Devise
  # you have to set mailers somehow, maybe with another filter
  unless current_user.company_id == @mailers.company_id
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```